# Como criar requestes criptografadas no ambiente de produção?

Tags: front-end, criptografia, back-end

Estava analisando uma aplicação frontend escrita em symfony(PHP), e ao abrir suas requestes me deparei com o conteúdo desta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei interessante pois o nome da request está criptografado assim como a url, o body, header:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Pergunta é simples, essa configuração é algo feito no backend, frontend ou no servidor? é alguma biblioteca? teria algum exemplo?

Acredito ser importante a todos, pois estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em react e gostaria de aplicar este conceito.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi, onde está a criptografia, pelas imagens, você fez uma requisição para http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/orders/create/modules/2 e esse URL foi convertido para http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/_wdt/b5c7c1 aparentemente não vi nenhuma criptografia neste ponto.

Simplesmente, isso é feito na tradução, da URL AMIGAVEL para a tradicional, esse nome, é o inicio da hash, usada para identificar a requisição, do próprio gzip/deflate para que exista uma criptografia os 2 interlocutores devem saber como criptografar e descriptografar a mensagem, ou seja, para trafegar os dados criptografados, tanto o front-end como o back-end tem que estar preparados para criar a string criptografada, e descriptografa-la para poder utilizar.

Não é um processo rápido, nem tão pouco extremamente simples, já que envolve conceitos matemáticos de chaves privadas, publicas e algoritmos de criptografia, e tanto para criptografar quanto para descriptografar é necessário um certo poder computacional (custo do algoritmo). E claro, você pode estar fazendo isso em camadas, pois se você usa o HTTPS ele em sí próprio já faz essa criptografia entre s 2 pontos, ou seja, se a mensagem entre os servidores for interceptada ou sniffada por exemplo ela esta criptografada pelo próprio protocolo.

Tudo na mensagem HTTPS é criptografado, incluindo os cabeçalhos, as requisições e respostas. E mesmo assim, você ainda pode adicionar uma camada de segurança extra trafegando dados em forma de hash por exemplo, para senhas, para validar conteúdos de arquivos binários, entre outros, onde o caminho seja somente de validação (por exemplo a senha, sempre que ela é gerada, um mesmo hash é gerado, porém, a partir do hash não é possivel saber o dado original). Quando é necessário converter de volta o texto, ai sim, temos criptografia, podemos de maneira bem simples (errada, por bem dizer, mais que vai elucidar o que eu digo) dizer que quando convertemos um texto usando o base64 como em:

```
Texto original: Olá, mundo!
Texto convertido para Base64: T2zDoSwgbXVuZG8h
```

Isso por si só é uma criptografia, já que podemos decodificar e voltar a ter os dados originais, porém, somo é um algoritmo extremamente simples para os padrões atuais, ele é totalmente inseguro para ser usado com o objetivo de criptografar algo por isso disse que é errado dizer que ele é um algoritmo criptográfico, algoritmos específicos para criptografia como o RSA.